# Change the Color of shape and 3D formatting

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, shapes

I want different color formatting, using `msoShapeStylePreset` to apply color using RGB.

When I tried to apply the color using RGB, it filled the shape with two colors, which is not what I intended.

The goal is that when any shape is selected, its color should change, while the rest of the shapes remain the same.
I also want the option to choose the color combination for both.
[image]

```vb
Sub Select1()
    Sheet1.Shapes("Group 1").ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset41
    Sheet1.Shapes("Shape1").ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset27
    With Sheet1.Shapes("Shape1").ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = msoBevelCircle
        .BevelTopInset = 6
        .BevelTopDepth = 6
    End With
End Sub

Sub Select2()
    Sheet1.Shapes("Group 1").ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset41
    Sheet1.Shapes("Shape2").ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset27
    With Sheet1.Shapes("Shape2").ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = msoBevelCircle
        .BevelTopInset = 6
        .BevelTopDepth = 6
    End With
End Sub
```

I want to change the color like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign macro for each shape

- Right click on a shape > `Assign Macro`, select `ShpClick`, click <kbd>OK</kbd>

```vb
Sub ShpClick()
    Dim HLColor As Long
    Dim sCaller As String
    HLColor = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' modify as needed
    sCaller = Application.Caller
    Sheet1.Shapes("Group 1").ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset9
    With Sheet1.Shapes(sCaller).Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = HLColor
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With Sheet1.Shapes(sCaller).ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = msoBevelCircle
        .BevelTopInset = 6
        .BevelTopDepth = 6
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]